# Information about MANIFEST.MF?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, classpath, manifest

I'd like to know what's a MANIFEST File In Java project and how to use it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

See [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html).

> JAR files can support a wide range of
>   functionality, including electronic
>   signing, version control, package
>   sealing, extensions, and others. What
>   gives JAR files the ability to be so
>   versatile? The answer is embodied in
>   the JAR file's manifest.
>
> The manifest is a special file that
>   can contain information about the
>   files packaged in a JAR file. By
>   tailoring this "meta" information that
>   the manifest contains, you enable the
>   JAR file to be used for a variety of
>   purposes.

Answer (score 1):

We can use MANIFEST file to define the entry point of the application adding classpath or package version for a JAR file . There is a short tutorial given here which i found very good . Hope it will help you .. Here's the link  [Click Here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-add-your-manifest-into-a-jar-file/)

Answer (score 0):

This file is like property file which is mainly used to indicate the starting point/class of your application and which jar files/classpath your app will use.

As said on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifest_file):

> On the Java platform, a manifest file
>   is a specific file contained within a
>   JAR archive. It is used to define
>   extension and package related data. It
>   is a metadata file that contains
>   name-value pairs organized in
>   different sections. If a JAR file is
>   intended to be used as an executable
>   file, the manifest file specifies the
>   main class of the application. The
>   manifest file is named MANIFEST.MF.

You will find useful information on [Oracle's site](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html).